# Calling endpoint in api from Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I have such a service

```
public Sell Sell(Guid guid, double Quantity)
{
    Sell sell = new Sell();
    var result = _connectionDB.States.Find(guid);
    sell.Name = result.Name;
    sell.EAN = result.EAN;
    sell.Profit = result.Profit;
    sell.Quantity = Quantity;
    sell.SellePriceBrutto = result.SellePriceBrutto;
    sell.GTU = result.GTU;
    sell.dateTimeSell = DateTime.Now;
    sell.PurchasePriceNetto = result.PurchasePriceNetto;
    sell.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    _connectionDB.Sells.Add(sell);
    result.Quantity = result.Quantity - Quantity;
    _connectionDB.SaveChanges();
    return sell;
}
```

And controller

```
[HttpPut("Sell")]
public IActionResult Sell(Guid guid, double Quantity)
{
    var result = _connectionDB.States.Find(guid);
    if (result == null)
    {
        return Ok("No product in DB");
    }
    if (result.Quantity < 0)
    {
        return Ok("No Quantiti product in DB");
    }
    var sell = _userService.Sell(guid, Quantity);
    return Ok(sell);
}
```

This function does the following:

On the basis of Id, it searches for a product, changes its quantity and adds it to the sold table.
Generating link:
`https://localhost:7038/api/Warhause/Sell?guid=76f42455-0885-4edb-9d0a-0ebdd7610e4f&Quantity=1`

On the swagger side it works fine.
Is there any function from HttpClient that calls such an endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, I didn't know that you can pass null in this function.
This works for me:

```
    private async Task Send()
    {
        await HttpClient.PutAsync($"api/Warhause/Sell?guid={Id}&Quantity={Amount}", null);
        await BlazoredModal.CloseAsync();
    }
```